# Tkinter - dragging mouse across disabled Textbox stops update()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a program that uses a some kind of widget that from the user's side, lists 'uneditable' and 'unselectable' lines of data.

The widget should also have a scrollbar so my widget options are a bit more limited from what I understand.

Furthermore, the application displays continuously updating numbers.

I went for a textbox - however, when I hold down left click and move my mouse across the textbox root.update() stops/waits.

I wrote some example code below to demonstrate this phenomenon.

```
import time
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x500")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.main_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")

        self.main_text_box = Text(self.main_frame)
        self.main_text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")
        self.main_text_box.tag_configure("bold", font = "Helvetica 50")
        self.main_text_box.insert(END, "Example text", "bold")
        self.main_text_box.configure(state = DISABLED)

    def update(self):
        self.root.update()


def main():
    application = App()
    time_start = time.time()
    while True:
        application.update()
        print("Program running, {} seconds since start".format(
            round(time.time() - time_start, 3)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When the user drags the mouse across the textbox, the print statement in

```
while True:
```

waits for root.update().

Basically, my question is: Is there any way to not have root.update() wait if the mouse is dragged across a disabled textbox?

(note - I'm new to this site so if I'm being unclear or something, please do point out what I could've done better in my question :))

Thanks!

edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using update() because in my actual program (which I didn't post b/c it's 800+ lines), I have other non-tkinter update() methods in the while loop so that I can update other data each frame.

Comment: You might have better luck using `root.mainloop()` as normal, and using `root.after()` to periodically update your timer.  I'm not sure how that would interact with dragging in a text field, and it will almost certainly stop if you drag the window itself - if you must keep going even in such situations, you need to use a separate thread or process.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the comment - I'm a bit unsure as to how implementing threading would work here, would I make a class for the text widget and apply threading to that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The print statement continues working as expected.

Comment: @Mike-SMT that's strange.. You clicked and dragged the mouse? Would the fact that I'm using a mac affect things?

Comment: There are some visual and functional differences between windows and mac per version of python that do pop up from time to time but I don't see why that would be the case here.

Comment: I could not reproduce on macos either.

Comment: I am willing to bet with a 95% certainty the fact that you are using `update()` in multiple places is likely the culprit for the strange behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I didn't call any other tkinter update() methods in my main program's while loop.

Comment: If you can provide a link to your full code I can take a look for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to manage the loop of the tkinter instance with `update()` the `mainloop()` will do this for you.

Instead lets write this where the class inherits from `Tk()` and then make the time print function part of the class. We can also use `after()` to update the print. Lastly we should set time_start to a class attribute to be used in our time function.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.time_start = time.time()

        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")

        self.main_text_box = tk.Text(self.main_frame)
        self.main_text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")
        self.main_text_box.tag_configure("bold", font = "Helvetica 50")
        self.main_text_box.insert("end", "Example text", "bold")
        self.main_text_box.configure(state = "disabled")
        self.time_check()

    def time_check(self):
        print("Program running, {} seconds since start".format(round(time.time() - self.time_start, 3)))
        self.after(100, self.time_check)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app = App()
    my_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! Please see the edit I made at the end of my question explaining why I used update().

Comment: I did see your edit and I still think you do not need the `update()` loop. It will be handled with the `mainloop()` if you are having issues with it not updating with the main loop then there might be some other cause as it should work fine.

Comment: ok - I just thought that calling mainloop() would only loop the root in the application class rather than other update() methods in the main() while loop.

Comment: As long as everything you need updated is within the Tkinter instance it will be part of the event loop that is ran ever 15ish milliseconds.

Comment: Ok this works! However, my main program has other non-tkinter classes that get updated and they aren't in the application class so mainloop wouldn't cover them.. - Would the best solution be to use threading with the application class - or is there a better way?

Comment: @Moosefeather if your other classes need to be constantly updated then you can use threading to keep them separate from the Tkinter instance. You may also be able to use the `after()` method to update your other classes as well but if they take a large amount of time to update (more than a 100ms or so) I would probably use threading so they don't affect your main Tk instance.

Comment: Thanks Mike, question answered.

Comment: @Moosefeather glad to help. GL

Answer (score 3):

I could not quite reproduce the problem described; however, some anti-patterns need correction in the code posted:

- Use mainloop instead of a while loop.
- avoid calling update, the mainloop handles that for you.
- Use root.after to repeatedly call a method.

I change your App class to have it inherit from `tk.Tk`; you could inherit from `Frame` instead; in this case, you have to provide a master to it.
I also placed the console printing in a function outside the class, as it felt more suitable to keep a console output separated.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.main_frame = Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")

        self.main_text_box = Text(self.main_frame)
        self.main_text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")
        self.main_text_box.tag_configure("bold", font = "Helvetica 50")
        self.main_text_box.insert(END, "Example text", "bold")
        self.main_text_box.configure(state = DISABLED)

        self._update_me()

    def _update_me(self):
        print_time()
        self.after(500, self._update_me)

def print_time():
    print("Program running, {} seconds since start".format(
            round(time.time() - time_start, 3)))

def main():
    application = App()
    application.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    time_start = time.time()
    main()
```

Comment: Basically the same thing as my answer. I do have one question thought. Why have `time_start` inside of the `print_time` function. This will not show the real time sense start of the program.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at your answer LOL. Good point, `time_start` should indeed be set first. here, have an upvote for your trouble.

Comment: Hey I used update() because of the reason I mentioned in an edit I made a few seconds ago - is there a better way around this? Also, thanks for your help!

Comment: Most times you not only don't need to manually call update, but also should not as it may adversely interfere with the queue of events.

Comment: Hey I tried to run this code, but unfortunately it has the same issue - if I leftclick & drag around the mouse around on the textbox, it drops frames (it's more visible if you lower the ms count to 20 or so)